# How do you make a static class in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `static` class in swift, is this possible? If so how?

I tried:

```
static class MyClass
```

but get the error `Declaration cannot be marked 'static'`

Comment: what is a 'static' class in your mind? If you want a singleton you can just create an instance in a module-local variable:
let myClass = MyClass()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no static class, but you can make one by just adding static methods only.

The problem is that (as of today) classes cannot have static properties, so you have 2 options:

- use a struct instead of a class, defining all its methods and properties as static
- use the singleton pattern

The second option is in my opinion a better solution, unless you have specific reason for not wanting it.

Answer (score 1):

`static` means no instance, so I would make it a struct with no initializer:

```
struct MyStruct {
    @available(*, unavailable) private init() {}

    static var foo = "foo"

    static func doSomething(a: String) -> String {
        return a + foo
    }
}
```