# swift - how to declare a static class within the project

Tags: swift2

Im new to Swift. How can I declare a static class so I don't have to instantiate it.

I will create a Theme class so there I can set all my colors, images, etc.

Is there any decorator such as:

```
static class Theme {
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a static class in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472801/how-do-you-make-a-static-class-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the class itself, the contents must be marked as static

```
class Theme {

  // static constant
  static let foo = "foo"

  // static variable
  static var foo2 : String { return "foo2" }

  // static method
  class func bar(x: Int) -> Int
  {
    return 2 * x
  }
}

let a = Theme.foo // "foo"
let b = Theme.foo2 // "foo2" 

let y = Theme.bar(10) // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`static` means no instance, so I would make it a struct with no initializer:

```
struct Theme {
    @available(*, unavailable) private init() {}

    static var foo = "foo"

    static func doSomething() {
        //...
    }
}
```